# best way to change OwnerCt for an object in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, listeners

I recieve an Ext.form.Panel with 2 items Ext.form.field.Text inside.
Then I add a 3rd object, an Ext.container.Container and I want to put previous items into the new container so I take the fields and add a listener as follows

```
listeners:{ 
  beforerender:function(){
    Ext.getCmp('myContainer').add(this) ;
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler or best way to do that?

Comment: You can try to subscribe the `added` event of `#myContainer`. Inside event handler find your 2 text items and add them to container (it will be in first argument).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you waiting until the component is about to render before you put it in the container? Why not just put it into the container in the first place. Perhaps update your OP with more details.

Comment: Hi Evan, I can't modify the form before because is part of a framework and I can't change certain code. Anyway the solution works, I just wanted to know if someone has a better approach for the situation